# Python 2.7 MySQL query with unicode

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, unicode

Run into a strange issue on inserting SQL statement via python MySQLdb.

Here is my query and execution results

```
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', passwd = 'root', db = 'test', use_unicode=True, charset = 'utf8')
cursor = mydb.cursor()


my_query = u"""
INSERT IGNORE INTO test.testtable
(`CompanyName`, `Ticker`, `Date`)
VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s");
"""

cursor.execute(my_query, (companyname, ticker, date))
```

This code runs ok if the variable **company/ticker/date** has no unicode characters.  However, if I get any unicode characters, the sql statement is simply not executed.

If I print out individual variables' value, they are correct, even for unicode strings.  If I don't pass SQL statement using variables, the following statement also works:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO test.testtable (`CompanyName`, `Ticker`, `Date`) VALUES (u"公司", u"代码", u"日期");")
```

However, if I try to use the % formatter, then I run into issues:

```
print my_query % (companyname, ticker, date)
```

gives the following exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So my question is how do I insert SQL statement using variables which could potentially have unicode strings.  I am feeling the old % formatter is the issue here, but I cannot find out how to use .format() formatter to pass SQL statement.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[*Notes on utf8 in Python*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python).  Perhaps the main statement there is

In the 1st or 2nd line in source code (to have literals in the code utf8-encoded):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I did have this line there, which is why my printing works.  however if I use the % formatter, it stopped working